# Database datetime format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

I use [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) plugin for jquery to build a grid.

I need to output the column date. From the database I get this:

```
{ts '2013-05-04 03:21:12'}
```

I would like to output something as `04-05-2013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string up and rearrange it.

```
var ts = "{ts '2013-05-04 03:21:12'}";
ts = ts.match(/'([^']+)'/)[1];  // or ts.split("'")[1]
var dt = ts.split(" ");
var date = dt[0];
var dateSplit = date.split("-");
var finalDate = dateSplit[2] + "-" + dateSplit[1] + "-" + dateSplit[0];
```

This is assuming the timestamp will always be in the format you provided (won't have other numbers/characters or be in different order).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/GQthr/1/

Comment: If you split on `'` instead, you can deal with the original `{ts ...}`.

Comment: @Mogsdad Instead of splitting on `'`, I'd rather use a regex. Anyways, I wasn't sure what the OP actually had access to - whether it was the full string or just the date/time. But that's a good point, so I updated my answer to hopefully accommodate that.

Comment: That `{ts ...}` is a common way that dates are expressed in some SQL installations. So it's a fair guess that the whole string is available.

Comment: @Mogsdad Didn't know that, so thanks for the info :) Does the update to my answer look/work right then?

Comment: Yeah... although I dislike resorting to regex. Personal pref.

Comment: @Mogsdad I try not to unless I think it's safe to use. I guess technically, a regex could be used for the whole thing, or splitting could be used for the whole thing, or they could be mixed and matched.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, that takes advantage of [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) and it's support for ISO 8601 formatted dates (which is what you have). I borrowed from @Ian's answer for the variable names.

```
var ts ="{ts '2013-05-04 03:21:12'}";

var dt = ts.split("'");
var date = new Date(Date.parse(dt[1].replace(' ','T')));
var finalDate = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

alert(finalDate);
```

Comment: Might as well fork my fiddle and use your code to show this works too!